# Why I can not get dxdy equals rdrdΘ?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$x = rcosΘ$

$y = rsinΘ$

$dx = -rsinΘdΘ + cosΘdr$

$dy = rcosΘdΘ + sinΘdr$

$dxdy = (-rsinΘdΘ + cosΘdr)(rcosΘdΘ + sinΘdr) 
= -r^2sinΘcosΘdΘ^2 - rsinΘ^2drdΘ + rcosΘ^2dΘdr + sinΘcosΘdr^2$

this seems can not be simplified to $rdrdΘ $

**why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heuristically you have
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
dx\\
dy
\end{pmatrix}
=&\ 
\begin{pmatrix}
-r\sin\theta & \cos\theta\\
r\cos\theta & \sin\theta
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
d\theta\\
dr
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
then it follows
\begin{align}
2dxdy=&\ 
dxdy-dydx\\
=&\ 
\begin{pmatrix}
dx, dy
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-1& 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
dx\\
dy
\end{pmatrix}\\
=&\  
\begin{pmatrix}
d\theta, dr
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-r\sin\theta & r\cos\theta\\
\cos\theta & \sin\theta
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-1& 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-r\sin\theta & \cos\theta\\
r\cos\theta & \sin\theta
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
d\theta\\
dr
\end{pmatrix}\\
=&\
\begin{pmatrix}
d\theta, dr
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -r\\
r& 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
d\theta\\
dr
\end{pmatrix}
= -r d\theta dr+rdr d\theta = 2rdrd\theta.
\end{align}

As a finally note, one can think of $dxdy$ as the signed area element generated by the two tangent vector $dx/ds$ and $dy/ds$, i.e.
\begin{align}
dxdy = \operatorname{sgn}(\sin\Theta)\left|\frac{dx}{ds}\times \frac{dy}{ds}\right|
\end{align}
where $s$ is the arc-length parametrization and $\Theta$ is the angle between the two vectors from "left to right". Then it's clear that $dxdy = -dydx$.

Comment: So  these' nothing between dx and dy, and dxdy is a whole notation,right?

Answer (score 1):

The order of $dr, d\Theta$ should be reversed in the middle two terms. The second term will then be $r\sin^2\Theta\, dr\, d\Theta$ as $d\Theta\, dr = -dr\, d\Theta$. The first and last terms are zero, so you'll be left with 
$$r\sin^2 \Theta\, dr\, d\Theta + r\cos^2\Theta\, dr\, d\Theta = (r\sin^2\Theta + r\cos^2\Theta)\, dr\, d\Theta = r\, dr\, d\Theta$$

Comment: Do you think that the OP is viewing the transformation in terms of the outer product?

Comment: No, I don't think so. It appears the OP did $dy\, dx$ instead of $dx\, dy$.

Comment: The OP retained the cross terms, which indicates that the OP is treating multiplication of the differentials incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, I agree. That's why I noted the errors in the cross terms. Unless the OP explains how his expansion was developed, I cannot say for certain how he's viewing the transformation. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Sure.  I would guess the OP is treating the differentials as numbers and simply and naively  multiplying as such.

Comment: yes.. I treated them as  naively multiplyin, I think dx and dy are just very small number of changes, they  are scalars, aren't they? I don't understand why dxdy = -dydx...

Comment: @monffy they are not scalars. I assumed you were computing $dx\, dy$ as a wedge product (but without the wedge symbol $\wedge$). You can review Jacky Chong's edit, for a way to see why $dx\, dy = -dy\, dx$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a geometric reason.

For small values of $r$ and $\theta$, a polar wedge is approximately rectangular. Using the arc length formula the wedge has dimensions $\Delta r$, "length", and $r \Delta \theta$, "width". Multiplying, you get $\Delta A = r \Delta r \Delta \theta$, which leads to the infinitesimal version $dA = r dr d \theta$.